# Generic IEnumerable

Tags: c#, silverlight

I Have a Generic IEnumerable which contains a list of my data. I need to try and access the data to put some of it into an object.

```
IEnumerable myData = DynamicDataBuilder.GetDataList(dataSetData);
ObservableCollection<Pages> myPages = new ObservableCollection<Pages>();

foreach (object item in myData)
{
    Pages myPage = new Pages
    {
        ID = ??????
    };
}
```

I cant cast myData as a ObservableCollection as not all the data in myData is of type Pages.
I have tried doing 
ID = item.Id - The item. only shows 'ToString', 'Equals', 'GetHashCode' and 'GetType'
ID = item["Id"] - Get error

Any help would be much appreciated

For reference here is the GetDataList method:

```
    public static IEnumerable GetDataList(DataSetData data)
    {
        if (data.Tables.Count() == 0)
            return null;

        DataTableInfo tableInfo = data.Tables[0];

        System.Type dataType = BuildDataObjectType(tableInfo.Columns, "MyDataObject");

        //ObservableCollection<DataObject> l = new ObservableCollection<DataObject>();

        var listType = typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { dataType });
        var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

        XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(data.DataXML);
        var table = from row in xd.Descendants(tableInfo.TableName)
                    select row.Elements().ToDictionary(r => r.Name, r => r.Value);

        foreach (var r in table)
        {
            var rowData = Activator.CreateInstance(dataType) as DataObject;
            if (rowData != null)
            {
                foreach (DataColumnInfo col in tableInfo.Columns)
                {
                    if (r.ContainsKey(col.ColumnName) && col.DataTypeName != typeof(System.Byte[]).FullName && col.DataTypeName != typeof(System.Guid).FullName)
                        rowData.SetFieldValue(col.ColumnName, r[col.ColumnName], true);
                }
            }
            listType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(list, new[] { rowData });
        }
        ObservableCollection<DataObject> l = list as ObservableCollection<DataObject>;
        return list as IEnumerable;
    }
```

Comment: what does `GetDataList` return?

Comment: Returns a IEnumerable. Method attached

Answer (score 2):

Just pull the relevant objects out using the `OfType` extension method

```
IEnumerable myData = DynamicDataBuilder.GetDataList(dataSetData);
IEnumerable<Page> PageCollection = myData.OfType<Page>();
```

Now you should be able to create an `ObservableCollection<Page>` from your strongly-typed `PageCollection` object

```
ObservableCollection<Pages> myPages 
       = new ObservableCollection<Pages>(PageCollection);
```

Comment: This is returning PageCollection as null.

Comment: It shouldn't.  Are you sure myData isn't null on the line before?

Comment: Positive - when i step through the code I can see the data and the values

Comment: That really really shouldn't be possible.  Wrap up your new code and ask a new question about why OfType() is returning null.  Title the question "OfType Extension method returns null" and you should get plenty of responses

Comment: I think its because the myData collection is not like any of my types. It is a collection of about 15 fields, 5 of which need added to my Page Object

Comment: It shouldn't matter; IEnumerable.OfType should never return null.  Post your url here if you ask that question. I'd like to see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm completely understanding you, but I think I'd try something like...

```
IEnumerable myData = DynamicDataBuilder.GetDataList(dataSetData);
ObservableCollection<Pages> myPages = new ObservableCollection<Pages>();
foreach (var item in myData)
{
    MyExpectedDataType data = item as MyExpectedDataType;
    If(data != null)
    { 
        Pages myPage = new Pages
        {
            ID = data.Id
        };
        MyPages.Add(myPage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable myData = DynamicDataBuilder.GetDataList(dataSetData);
ObservableCollection<Pages> myPages = new ObservableCollection<Pages>();
foreach (MyType item in myData) {
// ...
```

You can put the type you want in the `foreach` constuct.  Or use `OfType` extension as Adam says, in the case of .NET 3.5+

Comment: Get Unable to cast object of type 'MyDataObject' to type Pages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is because the `item` in your `foreach` loop is from `object` type.

```
foreach (object item in myData)
```

Just replace it with var keyword or use the actual type

```
foreach (var item in myData)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Even if it is a var I still get the same.

Comment: OK, use the actual type. `(yourType item in myData)`

Comment: Tried that aswell but get unable to cast object MyDataObject to type Pages